# Do multi-linear regression such that the sign of the coefficient is the same as the sign of correlation

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression

Suppose we have 3 variables:

1. $y$, $x_1$ and $x_2$,
2. $\text{Correlation}(y,x_1)=a_1>0$ and $\text{correlation}(y,x_2)=a_2>0$, (so when I do multi-linear regression, I want to get $y=c_1x_1+c_2x_2$ with $c_1>0$, $c_2>0$, but this is not always true.)
3. Then I do the multi-linear regression $y$ as a function $x_1$ and $x_2$, suppose we get $y=b_1x_1+b_2x_2$, but we may get $b_1<0$, $b_2>0$.

Then from 2, we know that $x_1$ and $y$ will change in the same direction (when $x_1$ increases, $y$ increases). However, in 3, we get $y=b_1x_1+b_2x_2$, if we fixed $x_2$, we can get that $x_1$ and $y$ will change in the opposite directions (when $x_1$ increases, $y$ decreases).

My question: **is there an easy way that when we do multi-linear regression such that the sign of the coefficient is the same as the sign of correlation?**

Comment: Welcome to the site, @nkhuyu. I don't fully understand your question. Are you worried about multicollinearity, or are you worried about finding an incorrect sign due to sampling error alone?

Comment: It is multicollinearity.

Comment: You say: in 3, we get y=b_1*x_1+b_2*x_2, if we fixed x_2, we can get that x_1 and y will change in the opposite directions. The problem is that if x_1 and x_2 are multicollinear, you cannot fix x_2 and at the same time let x_1 move. Of course, to avoid this trap, you need to be aware of multicollinearity to begin with.